# Place description doesn't exist on getDetails result

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

While using the `getPlacePredictions` function on the `AutocompleteService`, each result contains a `description` field.

For example, when querying "times square", the first result has a `description` of "Times Square, Manhattan, NY, USA".

After saving the `place_id` of this result, and using it for the `getDetails` function on the `PlacesService`, the same place does not contain the `description` field, but rather a field called `formatted_address` which contains "Manhattan, NY 10036, USA".

How can i get the original description received using the `AutocompleteService` when using the `PlacesService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because each service has different response, the getPlacePredictions will return predictions which each have a description.the description field only tells you what the matched prediction is.

When you use getDetails you get formatted address which should be more accurate that the descriptions, You can also iterate the long_name field through address_components to build your desired address format.

For your query you can actually see that in the respond under the "name" field you can see "Times Square" and in the "formated_address":Manhattan, NY 10036, USA. which is the actual address for this PLACE details you requested.

So maybe you just need to consider this "name" field in the placeDetails response.

If you strictly need the  value of "description" you can save this in a variable and use it as needed

Comment: I understand but since this description is associated with a place_id, i would expect it to be retrievable also the other direction.

Besides, in the example i gave, it clearly shows that the description is more accurate then the formatted_address, and when retrieving this place the string "Time Square" was nowhere to be found.

Comment: it would help a lot if you post your query so we can recreate it , so we can give you a better answer (recreated)

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1stimes&4sen-US&15e3&key=XXXXXX&callback=_xdc_._txs4t5&token=XXXXX

Comment: cant really do anything with this, can you post the place_id, and the input address that you give to  getPlacePredictions

Comment: ah yes, sorry, the place_id is "ChIJmQJIxlVYwokRLgeuocVOGVU" and the user input is "times"